# Integrating ASP.NET code to Active Directory or LDAP after deploying on Bluemix

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, paas

I'm working on an **ASP.Net** project, which needs to be deployed after completion on PaaS, which needs to be **BlueMix** (It wasn't my choice, It was an order).
In addition I need to use an:

> Active Directory or LDAP to the User Authentication and Authorization, integrated with the ASP.Net Project.

**The Issues Here Are :** 
**1.** I have found an integration to the Active Directory or SSO Services using only Java or Node.js, but in my case I am using ASP.Net 
**2.** I want a solution for how the integration can be done on top of the PaaS between the Active Directory and ASP.Net application.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which version of ADFS you're using, you should be able to use either OAuth or OIDC middleware to connect from an ASP.NET Core application (assuming you're using ASP.NET Core because you're using Bluemix).  If you're using at least ADFS 3.0 (Windows Server 2012+), you can use ASP.NET Core's generic OAuth middleware to connect.

First, create a configuration file to store your ADFS server settings, or modify an existing configuration file (such as appsettings.json).

Sample "adfs-settings.json" file:

```
{
  "ADFS": {
    "ClientId": "Your ClientId as set on ADFS server",
    "ResourceUrl": "url of this application (ex: http://mywebapp.mybluemix.net)",
    "ServerUrl": "url of ADFS (ex: https://dc.your.domain)"
  }
}
```

If you created a new file, such as "adfs-settings.json", for your ADFS configuration, add it to your `Configuration` object in the constructor of your Startup.cs file.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("adfs-settings.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

In your `Configure` method of Startup.cs create an `OAuthOptions` object:

```
var options = new OAuthOptions();
options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
options.AuthenticationScheme = "ADFS";
```

Specify the `ClientId` that you created when configuring this application on your ADFS server by reading it from your `Configuration` object.  The generic OAuth middleware also requires that you provide a `ClientSecret` here even though that value is not actually used by ADFS 3.0.

```
options.ClientId = Configuration["ADFS:ClientId"];
options.ClientSecret = "ADFS 3.0 does not support confidential client, but OAuth middleware requires it";
```

Set the callback url which the ADFS server will redirect to in your application.

```
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-adfs");
```

Now configure the `OAuthEvents`.  `OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint` defines parameters which are passed to the ADFS authorization endpoint when the application determines that a user needs to be authorized.  This will require at least a `resource` parameter which points to the url of your application.  `OnCreatingTicket` is triggered when the ADFS server has finished authorizing a client and returns a JWT token containing claims data to your application.  In this method you'll need to process adding roles and claims to the `HttpContext` object.

```
options.Events = new OAuthEvents {
    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
    {
        var parameter = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["resource"] = Configuration["ADFS:ResourceUrl"]
            };
        var query = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(context.RedirectUri, parameter);
        context.Response.Redirect(query);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnCreatingTicket = context => {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        JwtSecurityToken validatedToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(context.AccessToken);
        IEnumerable<Claim> a = validatedToken.Claims;

        foreach (var claim in a)
        {
            // role claim needs to be mapped to http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role
            // for IsInRole() to work properly
            if (claim.Type == "role")
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, claim.Value));
            }
            else if (claim.Type == "unique_name")
            {
                // map name to Identity.Name
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(context.Identity.NameClaimType, claim.Value));
            }
            else
            {
                // this is optional, if you want any other specific claims from Active Directory
                // this will also include some information about the jwt token such as the issue
                // and expire times
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Type, claim.Value));
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
```

Next, set the `ClaimsIssuer` to the ADFS url and set the `SignInScheme` to `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` and configure the `AuthorizationEndpoint` and `TokenEndpoint` to the proper endpoints on your ADFS server.

```
    options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["ADFS:ServerUrl"];
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["ADFS:ServerUrl"] + "/adfs/oauth2/authorize/";
    options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["ADFS:ServerUrl"] + "/adfs/oauth2/token/";
```

Finally, add the OAuth middleware using the options you've just created:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOAuthAuthentication(options);
```

Now you should be able to apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to any controller or action which requires authorization with ADFS.  For a complete sample application see [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/degrim/aspnet-core-ADFS).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful for generic ADFSv3 / OAuth. One thing that's missing is why `signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` returns null.

Comment: For the record: in my case, `signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` returned because missing claims.
ADFSv3 claim types don’t seem to follow the standard ones (hence we have to convert), but even that can mix things up. So, instead of the following:
`context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(context.Identity.NameClaimType, claim.Value));`

I had to use:
`context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, claim.Value));`